# How to determine Collapse operator for Lindblad equation for a specific case

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, quantum-statistics

The general form of a Lindblad equation has the form

$$\frac{d\rho}{dt}=-i[H,\rho]+\sum\gamma(A{\rho}A^{\dagger}-\frac{1}{2}A^{\dagger}A\rho-\frac{1}{2}\rho{A}^{\dagger}A)$$

How can I find Collapse operator for a specific case, For example, for a single Bosonic mode, For a purely gaussian process the Lindbladian is taken to be of the form given in this [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.04525).  Here for the Amplitude damping effect $A$ is taken as $\sqrt{2}a$ and $L^{\dagger}=\sqrt{2}a^{\dagger}$  and for the Purely Dephasing case $A=A^{\dagger}=\sqrt{2}a^{\dagger}a$.  But I don't understand how can I get these Collapse operators for these specific cases.

Comment: You may want to go the Hamiltonian $\rightarrow$ Redfield eq. (aka 2nd order in perturbation approximation) $\rightarrow$ Lindblad eq. way. Start with the purely dephasing Hamiltonian for a bosonic mode interacting with some thermal bath and have a look at http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/229319/relationship-between-the-lindblad-equation-and-redfield-equation/229416?noredirect=1#comment675373_229416 for general pointers on how to proceed.

Answer (score -4):

[image]

[image]

-----From Qutip 4.4.0 tutorial